# DensityPlot needed

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I want to make a DensityPlot showing $y(x)$ plotted against $x$ and $\alpha$, with the following differential equations

```
α = 1
NDSolve[{α*y'''[x] + 8 y''[x] + 17 y'[x] + 10 y[x] == 0, 
   y[0] == 6*α, y'[0] == -20, y''[0] == 84}, y, {x, 0, 1}];
Plot[Evaluate[y[x] /. %], {x, 0, 1}]
```

where $\alpha$ is varied between 1 and 2.

Answer (score 2):

You want the fantastic function [`ParametricNDSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricNDSolve.html):

```
Clear[α]

sol = ParametricNDSolve[{
   α y'''[x] + 8 y''[x] + 17 y'[x] + 10 y[x] == 0,
   y[0] == 6 α,
   y'[0] == -20,
   y''[0] == 84}, 
  y, {x, 0, 1}, {α}]

DensityPlot[Evaluate[y[α][x] /. sol], {x, 0, 1}, {α, 1, 2}, 
 FrameLabel -> {x, α}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This differential equation is quite simple. So you can solve it analytically.

```
y[x_, α_] = FullSimplify[y[x] /. First@
DSolve[{α*y'''[x] + 8 y''[x] + 17 y'[x] + 10 y[x] == 0, 
        y[0] == 6*α, y'[0] == -20, y''[0] == 84}, y, x], 0 >= x <= 1 && 1 <= α <= 2]
```

The is result not shown here.

And plot the DensityPlot

```
DensityPlot[y[x, α], {x, 0, 1}, {α, 1, 2}]
```